# Add class and extra HTML to specific menu items with hook

Tags: 7, routes

In page.tpl.php I have the following to echo out the main menu:

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
        <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'top', 'class' => array('links')))); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The site is responsive so on desktop monitors it displays like this:

[image]

But as you reduce the screen to mobile size it turns into a navigation list that can be opened and closed with a button. See here:

[image]

However the desired effect is to have small descriptions for each of the menu items in the mobile version simply by using `<p class="monly">little description</p>` wrapped within the menu li and a tags. See here:

[image]

I also want to add CSS class *'nobile'* to tthe list item 'Home' in the menu so that it doesn't display on the mobile version.

So how can I add this CSS class to the 'Home' `<li>`? And how do I go about adding the link descriptions to each `<li>`? Can I use a hook in template.php? If so how do I go about this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You can add a custom class to menu items by using the [Menu Attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. You can also use `hook_menu_link` for the same. For displaying the menu description, here is a sample code. Paste it in your template.php file

```
/**
* Implements theme_menu_link().
* Adds menu description under main menu 
*/
function themename_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;


  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu" && isset($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'])){
    $element['#title'] .= '<span class="description">' . $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] . '</span>';
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

**Note :** You've to use css/js to show/hide the menu description based on the screen size.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sharan! any chance of adding comments to this function? Added it, and doesn't seem to have changed anything. But hard for me to debug because I don't really understand what is happening :P :S

Comment: I'll try to add few comments in the function...

Comment: Hey @Sharan I can't seem to get this working and displaying the description when I put it in template.php :S Have you tested it yourself?

Comment: Ya I tested it on my site... Did you replace theme_menu_link with your theme name ? Anyways I updated the code above to account for any typo... Check now and tell me the result...

Comment: Yes set the theme name @Sharan. Could it be because I'm printing the menu like this `<?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'top', 'class' => array('links')))); ?>` ?

Comment: Oops sorry, I didn't notice that... It might be the problem... Try using the main-menu block instead of hard coding the menu and check if the menu description is rendered...

Comment: Can I not somehow change the function to work with this existing way of printing the menu?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if we can change the theme_menu_link function. It's a very basic function and also works perfectly. But you can try to change your theme() render function and see if it works.